# Creating a Four in a Row grid in Java

Tags: java

**Hi all,**

**I'm fairly new to using GUI in java and I'm supposed to create a grid. However, I'm not very sure how to use JLabels, JFrames etc or how to even start. As such, can someone explain it in a 'simplified' manner or briefly go over how to start? The description is as follows:**

Write the class GUICF that inherits CFGame. ConsoleCF is a graphical implementation of the
Connect Four game. GUICF should have the following fields, contructors, methods, and inner
class.

The private field

```
private GameBoard this board;
```

represents the graphics for the 6 × 7 board, but not the buttons.

The constructor

```
public GUICF(CFPlayer ai)
```

sets up and starts a human vs. AI game, where the red player (the player who goes first) is randomly
decided.

The constructor

```
public GUICF(CFPlayer ai1, CFPlayer ai2)
```

sets up and starts an AI vs. AI game, where the red player (the player who goes first) is randomly
decided.

A human vs. AI game and an AI vs. AI game creates slightly different GUIs. A human vs. AI game
will have a graphical interface like Figure 1. At each turn, the AI makes the move automatically
and the human player’s move is specified through clicking a button. An AI vs. AI game will have
a graphical interface like Figure 2. When you click the “Play” the next AI makes the next move.

The private method playGUI

```
private boolean playGUI(int c)
```

plays the column c. So the internal game logic inherited from CFGame and the displayed board
represented in this_board must be updated. If c is a column that can be played, play the column
and return true. Otherwise return false and do not update the state of the game.

Write the private class

```
private class GameBoard extends javax.swing.JPanel {
private GameBoard() {
// initialize empty board
...
}
private void paint(int x, int y, int color) {
//paints specified coordinate red or black
...
}
}
```

that represents the game board. In real life, the game pieces are circular, but in GameBoard they
can be square. These square pieces can be done with 6*7=42 JLabels and a GridLayout. (You
may want to use setOpaque(...) with the JLabels.)
The GameBoard does not include the buttons.

**So far, my code is essentially useless, but here it is anyway:**

```
package hw4;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GUICF extends CFGame{
    private GameBoard this_board;

    private class GameBoard extends javax.swing.JPanel {
        private JFrame frame;
        private int x = 7;
        private int y = 6;

        private GameBoard() {
            frame = new JFrame("CF");

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 7));

            for(int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
                    JLabel shape = new JLabel();
                    shape.setOpaque(true);
                    shape.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
                    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
                    panel.add(shape);
                }
            }
            add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            panel.setVisible(true);

            frame.setContentPane(panel);
            frame.setSize(700, 600);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        }

        private void paint(int x, int y, int color) {

        }
    }
}
```

**Any assistance is much appreciated.**

Comment: Hi Tronix. This is a poor question. You can improve it by narrowing your question, like "I am struggling with x". As it is, it looks like you just want us to do your homework / project for you

Comment: I understand. I don't want anyone to actually do the code for me though; I'd just like someone to explain what I can do to proceed cause I'm lost right now...

Comment: I'm sorry, but asking "what can I do to proceed" is too broad... There are many ways to proceed. And because of this, I have voted to close your question as too broad. But the way *I* would do it would be to build a connect-4 game model (no graphics) first, and then once that's finished and tested, look to add a GUI around it.